# specify value options_for_select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 helpers:

```
all_currencies(Money::Currency.table)
all_currencies_values(Money::Currency.table)
```

Each helper is an array with differents values:

Helper 1:

```
["ZWN, Zimbabwean Dollar, $", "ZWR, Zimbabwean Dollar, $"]
```

Helper 2:

```
["ZWN", "ZWR"]
```

I need specify the second helper in value attribute of select field. I have tried with this:

```
<%= select_tag "currency", all_currencies_values(Money::Currency.table)), options_for_select(all_currencies(Money::Currency.table), :prompt => "Select currency" %>
```

but I get the same result in both, text and value of select field:

**How can I add the helper 2 `all_currencies_values(Money::Currency.table)` to the select field value and helper 1 in select field text?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options_for_select` is looking for the text/value pairings. So you could do this:

```
<%=
   money_text = all_currencies(Money::Currency.table)
   money_values = all_currencies_values(Money::Currency.table)
   select_tag "currency", options_for_select(money_text.zip(money_values)), :prompt => "Select currency"
%>
```

Or, create a helper (e.g., `currency_selects`) that already gives you the text/value pairings as `[[text1, val1], [text2, val2], ...]` and do it in one line:

```
<%= select_tag "currency", options_for_select(currency_selects(Money::Currency.table), :prompt => "Select currency" %>
```